# School timetable software

Tags: linux, project-management

I am a high school teacher and I want a piece software to create a school timetable.

I want to just feed it with the class lessons and teachers.  For the teacher section, I want to just provide it with subjects being taught by the teacher; after that I want it to autogenerate the timetable.

In Windows I saw aSc timetable, but what can I have for Linux? I’m using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Did you try runnnng your Windows program in Linux using Wine? Most run just fine

Comment: Take alook at https://sourceforge.net/directory/os:linux/?q=school+timetable# You *might* find something there. If you do, please post it as an answer and accept your own answer, as that will help others in future.

Comment: Have you tried [FET](http://www.lalescu.ro/liviu/fet/)? Haven't tried it myself, but looks promising: runs on Linux (open source and free) and has lots of features and constraints, like time constraints related to teachers/students/subjects. Maybe worth a look.

Comment: Would you have the courtesy to reply to comments, please? We are trying to help you

Comment: I ended up installing FET, it works fine